# How to access a folder with a specific name by iterating through various subdirectories - Python?

Tags: python, directory, path, glob, subdirectory

I would like to access the "PNG FILES" folder that are randomly located in various different subdirectories of my 'All images' folder. I have tried the following:

```
import glob

path = r"C:\main folder\All images"
for f in glob.iglob((path) + 'PNG FILES', recursive=True):
    print (f)
```

However, this does not give me an output. I know you can easily locate files with a certain extension using glob.iglob but I'm having trouble locating folders with a specific name ('PNG FILES' in this case).
Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you save the path of the folder you want to a variable and check if the path of each file matches it?

Comment: Your just missing a backslash: `(path) + 'PNG FILES'` will result in `r'C:\main folder\All imagesPNG FILES'`, and that's probably not what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk and then check the folder names in the loop.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirs:
        if name == 'PNG FILES':
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the standard `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = r"C:\main folder\All images"
for folder_path in Path(path).glob("**/PNG FILES"):
    print(folder_path)
```